# Nuxt 3 + Vite: Rollup failed to resolve import "vue-router"

Tags: vue-router, vite, nuxtjs3, rollupjs

During the build process of my Nuxt 3 application, the following error message appears:

```
[vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "vue-router" from "[...]/node_modules/nuxt/dist/app/components/test-component-wrapper.js".
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
build.rollupOptions.external
```

The application runs stably locally.

What does this error mean and how can I fix it?

I look forward to feedback!

Best regards,
Tobi

**Setup:**

- nuxt 3.5.2
- vite/4.3.1
- linux-x64 node-v18.14.2

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by simply deleting `node_modules` + `package-lock.json`.

`npm run build` then ran smoothly.

Apparently something was "wired" wrong.

Best regards, Tobi

Answer (score 3):

As [Tobi360](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6449514/tobi360) mentioned above, removing `node_modules` + `package-lock.json` will do the job.

In my case, I have both `package-lock.json` and `yarn.lock`, so I had to:

```bash
$ rm -f node_modules/
$ rm package-lock.json
$ yarn install
$ rm -rm .nuxt/
$ yarn generate
```

EDIT: I also had to delete `.nuxt/`

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by simply deleting node_modules + package-lock.json + .nuxt, then npm i -f ,then you can run your nuxt-demo successful